# What package is necessary to install for the getacl command?

Tags: linux, centos, filesystems, acl

CentOS 6.3

I'm studying Access Control Lists and for some reason, the getacl command isn't available.  When I try running it, I get:

```
[root@foobox test] getacl test.txt
-bash: getacl: command not found
```

But if I grep RPM for packages, I see that **acl-2.2.49-6.el6.x86_64** is installed. Perhaps this isn't the right package?

I've also confirmed that the filesystem mount has the acl option associated with it.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why the vote to close? Admittedly I was typing the wrong command but I don't think it's grounds for closing the entire question.

Comment: Well, a simple typo is not really a worthwhile question that will help a lot of other users in the future...

Comment: @MartinvonWittich I see your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is not called `getacl`, but `getfacl`.